# Function that removes element if it exists but adds it of it does not

Tags: list, haskell

I'm looking for a cleaner way to write a function that adds an element to a list if the list does not contain it. Or otherwise removes it if the list does contain it, I'm using an `if` clause now and the function is working.

But I'm trying to find a more *haskell-ish* way to right this.

This is my code:

```
removeElemOrAdd :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeElemOrAdd elem list = if (List.elem elem list)
                            then (filter(\x -> x /= elem) list)
                            else (elem:list)
```

Comment: What kind of 'cleaner' are you seeking? Regarding conciseness, your solution looks good. Regarding performance, you can scan the list once for looking, removing, and adding, but it will be longer. (BTW the symmetry is broken by design:  you remove all matching elements but add only one.)

Comment: Generally, this looks good to me - you could I guess use a guard instead of an if/then/else, but it would run in the same way (recursively) which is 'haskellish'. @9000 makes a great point about the symmetry here though

Comment: What if the element occurs two or more times?

Comment: @9000: not only with respect to performance. This approach wil have a problem if it is used on an "*infinite*" list. Since it will never reach the `then` or `else`.

Comment: @CommuSoft: it's really hard to _definitely_ say if an item is absent from an infinite list, so I think that infinite sequences are ruled out by definition. Removing an item from an infinite list is of course possible, but you have to know that it's there to do this, which somehow defeats the purpose.

Comment: @9000: the point is that you can postpone the decision until you reach the end of the list (something that will never happen for an infinite list) and then add the item as the last element: so each time you have to enumerate you do equality checks. From the moment you find such element, you do no longer care about adding an element to the tail. The point is that you do not know in advance who will call your function, and with what.

Comment: @CommuSoft, you [can](http://ideone.com/kaNKAQ) postpone the decision even if you add the item as the first element, but the function then produces only the spine of a list.

Comment: @user3237465: yes, that's indeed a nice way to do this (+1). Although I still think it makes sense to add it as the last element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** a small ambiguity in your question is what to do when `x` already occurs *multiple* times in the original list. I assumed this won't happen and in case it does, only the *first* occurrence is removed. Meaning that `removeElemOrAdd 2 [4,2,5,2,7]` will result in `[4,5,2,7]`. Furthermore it is unspecified where the item should be added. Because it has some advantages, I've opted to do this at the end of the list.

An implementation without using any library methods is the following:

```
removeElemOrAdd :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeElemOrAdd x (y:ys) | x == y = ys
                         | otherwise = y : removeElemOrAdd x ys
removeElemOrAdd x _ = [x]
```

Or a shorter version:

```
removeElemOrAdd :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeElemOrAdd x = reoa
    where reoa (y:ys) | x == y = ys
                      | otherwise = y : reoa ys
          reoa _ = [x]
```

or an equivalent implementation (see discussion below):

```
removeElemOrAdd :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeElemOrAdd x = reoa
    where reoa (y:ys) | x == y = ys
                      | otherwise = y : reoa ys
          reoa [] = [x]
```

The function works as follows: in case we are talking about a list with at least one item `(y:ys)`, we compare `x` with `y` and if they are equal, we return `ys`: in that case we have removed the element and we are done.

Now in case the two are not equal, we return a list construction `(:)` with `y` in the head since we need to retain `y` and in the tail, we will do a recursive call `removeElemOrAdd` with `x` and `ys`. Indeed: it is possible that there is an `x` somewhere in the tail `ys` to remove, and furthermore we still need to add `x` to the list if it does not occur.

That clause will loop recursively through the list. From the moment it finds an `y` such that `x == y` it will remove that `y`. It is however possible that we reach the end of the list, and still have not found the element. In that case we will call the final clause. Here we know the list is empty (we could have written `removeElemOrAdd x []`) but to make the function definition syntactically total, I have opted to use an underscore. We can only reach this state if we have failed to find `x` in the list, so then we add it to the tail of the list by returning `[x]`.

An advantage of this approach over using the `if-then-else` is that this does all tasks at once (checking, removing and adding) making it more efficient.

Another advantage is that this can run on an "*infinite*" list (like for instance the list of prime numbers). The list is evaluated lazily, so if you want to take the first three items, this function will only check the equality of the first three items.

Comment: The wildcard patterns here feel weird, since it can only match one thing. My brain kept checking for a guard fall-through. Why not replace them with `[]` patterns?

Comment: @dfeuer: it is indeed equivalent with `[]`. The point is that you can say that the function is *syntactically* total: without having to check the semantics of the function you know that either the function will get stuck in an infinite loop or give an answer, but will never do pattern matching below the function definition (and fail).

Comment: This "syntactic" totality does not strike me as a valuable thing at all. The first pattern's guards include an `otherwise` clause, and the list type only has two constructors, so coverage is immediately apparent in any case. In the case of a data type whose definition could potentially change (unlike lists), I prefer to avoid wildcards that could defeat GHC's coverage checking. As I mentioned, in this context, the wildcard sent me the false message that the guards could fall through.

Answer (score 1):

I like the other approaches, but don't like that they behave differently than the specification. So here is an approach that:

1. Like the original, deletes all copies, if there are any, AND
2. like the original, inserts the new value at the beginning, if necessary, BUT
3. unlike the original, uses a clever trick based on the ideas of [beautiful folding](http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html) (and follow-up developments) to make only one pass through the data.

The basic idea is that we will have a single value which tracks both whether all values so far have been a mismatch as well as the resulting filtered list. The `injectNE` operation will perform this operation for a single element of the list, and we will then use `foldMap` to expand from one element to the whole input list.

```
import Data.Monoid

injectNE :: Eq a => a -> a -> (All, [a])
injectNE old new = (All ne, [new | ne]) where
    ne = old /= new

removeElemOrAdd :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeElemOrAdd x xs = case foldMap (injectNE x) xs of
    (All nex, noxs) -> [x | nex] ++ noxs
```

In the final pattern, you should read `nex` as "no element was equal to `x`", and `noxs` as "the list without any copies of `x`" (get it? "no `x`s"? ba-dum-tsh).

It is slightly unfortunate that the spec was written the way it was, though: in particular, one of the selling points of beautiful folding is that its resulting one-pass folds can be friendlier to the garbage collector. But the spec makes that quite hard, because we must traverse the entire input list before deciding what the first element of the result list should be. We can improve the friendliness to the garbage collector significantly by relaxing point (2) above (but leaving (1) and (3)); and moreover the difference is merely swapping the arguments to `(++)`, a nicely semantic diff to see in your revision history:

```
-- <snipped identical code>
removeElemOrAdd x xs = case ... of
    ... -> noxs ++ [x | nex]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a fold to remove all copies:

```
removeOrAdd x xs = foldr go (bool [x] []) xs False where
  go y r found
    | y == x = r True
    | otherwise = y : r found
```

To remove just one, a paramorphism seems to be in order:

```
removeOrAdd x = para go [x] where
  go y ys r
    | y == x = ys
    | otherwise = y : r
```